# How do I add a template to PcGen

Tags: pathfinder-1e, tools, pcgen

I'd like to add the [Terror Template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/terror-creature-cr-0/) to PcGen for my players to pick.
I do not understand the file format and can't finde the template editor tool advertised.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind linking to one of the PCGen Templates? <br /><br />I can take a crack at it but I am unable to find anything labeled "Template" in the PCGen GitHub.

Comment: The templates are all in a templates.lst file specific to that book. https://github.com/PCGen/pcgen/blob/master/data/pathfinder/paizo/roleplaying_game/core_rulebook/cr_templates.lst

Comment: Paul's link is a good start, I'm talking about race templates like half-fiend and half-celestial etc. (see https://github.com/PCGen/pcgen/blob/master/data/pathfinder/paizo/roleplaying_game/bestiary/b1_templates.lst)

I just don't get the file structure to create my own. I hope to avoid the effort of completely reverse engineering the structure.

Also, I found a template editor for PcGen, but can find it nowhere in my installation http://pcgen.org/autobuilds/pcgen-docs/menupages/tools/template/templateeditorbasetab.html

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: There are probably multiple ways of defining abilities and templates in PCGen. The solution below is the one I implemented and tested.*

First, define the Terror creature's special abilities. The ability descriptions below are based on [the wording of the Terror Creature template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/terror-creature-cr-0/). In PCGen definition syntax, each gets its own line. Also note the tab separation before each capitalized keyword - that is intentional.

> `Negative Energy Absorption       KEY:Terror Creature ~ Negative Energy Absorption            CATEGORY:Special Ability    TYPE:SpecialQuality.Supernatural    DESC:Heals 1 hit point for every 3 points of damage that negative energy attacks would otherwise deal; a terror creature gets no saving throw against negative energy effects.`
>
> `Immunity to Fear Effects      CATEGORY:Special Ability    TYPE:SpecialQuality.Extraordinary.Immunity      DESC:You are immune to fear effects.    ASPECT:Immunity|Fear Effects`
>
> `Fear Aura     KEY:Terror Creature ~ Fear Aura     CATEGORY:Special Ability    TYPE:SpecialQuality.Supernatural.Aura   DEFINE:TerrorFearAuraDC|0   DESC:20 Ft., as Fear spell, DC %1|TerrorFearAuraDC  BONUS:VAR|TerrorFearAuraDC|10+(HD/2)+CHA`

I put these 3 lines in the default homebrew file `my_homebrew\my_abilities.lst`.

Second, define the template itself. Fortunately, Darkvision is already defined for us, as well as the alignment kit (1) that changes the alignment (rather than requiring a prerequisite alignment):

> `Terror       CR:0    BONUS:VAR|DarkvisionRange|60|TYPE=Base  ABILITY:Special Ability|AUTOMATIC|Immunity to Fear Effects|Terror Creature ~ Fear Aura|Terror Creature ~ Negative Energy Absorption     KIT:1|NE`

I put this line in the default homebrew file `my_homebrew\my_templates.lst`.

Finally, when you load your sources, include the source for your homebrew content. Then, when creating a new creature sheet, go to the Templates tab. Scroll down and select "Terror", then hit the "Add Template" button. And that's it! The changes should be visible on the Character Sheet tab.