# How do I add the Phrenic Spawn Creature Template to PCgen?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-templates, pcgen

I want to add the [Phrenic Spawn Template](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/phrenic-spawn-creature-cr-2/) to PCgen. How would I go about doing this? Specifically, most of the regeneration and things like that I do not know how to add.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Thank you for editing my comment as to be more streamlined, Someone_Evil

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about how to use a tool related to RPGs, rather than anything directly related to RPGs.

Comment: There's a history of allowing questions about creating PCGen templates, but I could see stopping doing so. I do think there is merit in that you would have to have knowledge of the Phrenic Spawn Template (or be able to parse the information at the link quickly). I don't think PCGen is well supported by this community though, so you may have better luck elsewhere. [ref1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112730/building-the-template-for-a-half-elf-nymph-in-pcgen) [ref2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104544/how-do-i-add-a-template-to-pcgen)

Comment: @YogoZuno Using tools related to RPGs is explicitly [called out as on-topic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in our topic help pages. This specific type of question (how to create/add new material in PCGen) is well represented in the [[tag:pcgen]] tag too.